# Program can't find a specific value in a csv dataset

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a program that takes a CSV file from GitHub and graphs covid cases using matplotlib.

I added comments to the program so it should be self explanatory.

The first part of the code is the error, the second part is the program itself.

It gives me this error, from what i understand it can't locate the Orange county data.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621 in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136 in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163 in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198 in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206 in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Orange'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\OneDrive\Desktop\CSC 314\untitled0.py:48 in <module>
    df.loc["Orange"]

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:967 in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1202 in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1153 in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3864 in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623 in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'Orange'
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


# Download the data from the internet
covid_url  = "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/raw/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/"
covid_file = "time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv"
covid = pd.read_csv(covid_url + covid_file, delimiter=",")

# Basic cleanup
covid = covid.rename(columns={"Admin2":"County", "Province_State":"State"})
unused_columns = ["UID", "iso2", "iso3", "code3", "FIPS", "Long_", "Lat", "Country_Region", "Combined_Key"]
covid = covid.drop(columns=unused_columns)

col_a = covid.columns.get_loc("1/22/20")                  # Index of the first data column
col_z = covid.shape[1]-1                                  # Index of the last column

for c in range(col_z, col_a, -1):                         # Walk backwards from the last column
     covid.iloc[:, c] = covid.iloc[:,c] - covid.iloc[:,c-1]# Perform the subtraction
     
#merge the csv and txt datasets    
stats = pd.read_csv("california_county_stats.txt", delimiter=",")
covid = covid.set_index("County")
#filter down to CA counties and *then* perform the merge
covid = covid[covid["State"] == "California"]
covid = covid.drop(columns=['State'])
df = pd.merge(stats, covid, left_index=True, right_index=True)

first_column = df.columns.get_loc("1/22/20")
last_column = df.shape[1]-1
# Let's get the x- and y-values
df.loc["Orange"]
df.loc["Orange"][first_column:last_column]
y_vals = df.loc["Orange"][first_column:last_column]
x_vals = df.loc["Orange"][first_column:last_column].index

x_vals = [datetime.strptime(day, '%m/%d/%y') for day in x_vals]

# Plot the daily COVID case statistics for Orange County
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.gca().yaxis.grid()
plt.bar(x_vals, y_vals, width=1, color="orangered")
plt.title("Daily New COVID-19 Cases in Orange County", fontsize=14, pad=15)
plt.show()

# Create a copy of the original dataframe to work from
df = covid.copy()
# Average the last seven days worth of positive COVID tests
df["sum"] = df.iloc[:,last_column-7:last_column].sum(axis=1)
df["avg"] = round(df["sum"] / 7, 1)

# Plot the data
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.gca().yaxis.grid()
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, "-", color="orangered")
plt.fill_between(x_vals, y_vals, color="orangered", alpha=0.4)
plt.title("Daily New COVID-19 Cases in Orange County (7-Day Rolling Average)", fontsize=14, pad=15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: To replicate the error: From where do you get the file `california_county_stats.txt`? And what is the printout of `df` immediately after you created it by merging `stats` and `covid`?

Comment: california_county_stats.txt looks like this:                       
County,Lat,Lon,Population,Area
Alameda,37.64629437,-121.8929271,1671329,738
Alpine,38.59678594,-119.82235940000001,1129,739
Amador,38.44583082,-120.65696000000001,39752,606
Butte,39.66727762,-121.6005252,219186,1640
Calaveras,38.20537103,-120.55291299999999,45905,1020
Colusa,39.17881957,-122.2331726,21547,1151
Contra Costa,37.91923498,-121.9289527,1153526,720
Del Norte,41.74228275,-123.89740630000001,27812,1008
El Dorado,38.77965956,-120.5233166,192843,1712
Fresno,36.75733899,-119.6466953,999101,5963

Comment: but i tried even without merging the .txt and .csv data files and i still get the same error

Comment: Is this the full printout of `df`? `Orange` is not in there and therefore no values for this county can be merged. And I tried your code (w/o `stats`) and it works. `covid` can be index with `covid["Orange"]`. It seems likely that the merge doesn't yield a dataframe that contains value `Orange` in the index. This is basically what the error message says.

Comment: From where have you downloaded the `stats` data? It would be very helpful to have a minimal replicable example of your code to find the error.

Comment: Yes, Orange is in the txt file: Orange,33.70147516,-117.76459979999998,3175692,948

Comment: We need to know if the merge is successful. What is the printout of `df`?

Comment: It says that some columns or the whole df is empty                                                                                         Output from spyder call 'get_namespace_view':
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [County, Lat, Lon, Population_x, Area, Population_y, 1/22/20, 1/23/20, 1/24/20, 1/25/20, 1/26/20, 1/27/20, 1/28/20, 1/29/20, 1/30/20, 1/31/20, 2/1/20, 2/2/20, 2/3/20, 2/4/20, 2/5/20, 2/6/20, 2/7/20, 2/8/20, 2/9/20, 2/10/20, 2/11/20, 2/12/20, 2/13/20, 2/14/20, 2/15/20, 2/16/20, 2/17/20, 2/18/20, 2/19/20, 2/20/20, 2/21/20, 2/22/20, .....

[0 rows x 1034 columns]

Comment: Ok. Than this is the problem. Two things: Try to set the index of `stats` to `County`, like you did with `covid`. Second: Provide a link to the `stats` data file or reduce your code to an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please also do not add code/data information in your comments but rather add these in your original posting.

Comment: For your merge to work both dataframes need to have indexes that contains matching values. I suspect that `stats` has a regular index (just ascending ints). Therefore you do not get a match with the values in `covid`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the index of `stats` to `County` in order to merge the two dataframes. Add this line to your code:

```
stats = pd.read_csv("california_county_stats.txt", delimiter=",")
covid = covid.set_index("County")
stats = stats.set_index("County") # <- add this
...
```